# How can Greek manuscripts be intelligible with Hebrew characters placed in it?

Tags: greek

In certain old fragments of the Greek Septuigent the name of YHWH alone is written in paleo-Hebrew letters. I’m a novice at Greek, but isn’t it necessary for all proper nouns and names to be written with the proper case ending attached to it? How would that work if a name in hebrew is placed in a sentence? Would the sentence still make sense?

I’m currently learning biblical Greek and an answer to this question would help my understanding of the language.

Comment: This seems more relevant to Biblical Hermeneutics stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The LXX only ever translates YHWH to:

- κύριος
- ὁ θεὸς
- κύριος ὁ θεὸς

Supposing there is a case of a fragment using paleo-Hebrew to write the name, it would obviously not use Greek case endings. Case would be implied by context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be easy to figure out the case ending?